# vuejs computed setter of given prop is not reactive

Tags: vue.js

I'm using computed to copy my prop value and use/mutate it in my component:

```
export default {
  props: ['propOffer'],
  computed: {
    offer: {
      get: function () {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.propOffer))          
      },
      set: function () {
        this.offer
      }
    },
   }
```

The problem is within using setter. It is not reactive. When I use some kind of input, there is a delay, so my computed offer isn't updating instantly. Example of input:

```
    <v-text-field
    label="Offer title"
    v-model="offer.title"
    ></v-text-field>
```

This is far opposite to the behaviour when I declare `offer` as a variable (wthout computed) - then I got my `{{offer}}` changes instantly inside the `<template>`

How can I improve it? Am I setting my computed wrong?

Comment: Is the code inside your set method correctly pasted into your question? only having `this.offer` inside the setter has no observable effects

Comment: @Ferrybig I also wrote `set: function (value) {this.offer = value}`, but it has the same effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To better understand this situation, this is what happens at the moment:

When the application loads, the initial state is:

```
<your-component>
propOffer: '{"title":"test"}'
offer.<lastValue>: undefined
```

At the point in time, your application will load the `v-text-field`, this references field `offer`, and this inits the `offer` computed variable:

```
<your-component>
propOffer: '{"title":"test"}'
offer.<lastValue>: [Javascript object 1]

[Javascript object 1]
title: "test"

<v-text-field>
value: "test"
```

As the user types into the `v-text-field`, its value changes, because the `v-model` emits back updates:

```
<your-component>
propOffer: '{"title":"test"}'
offer.<lastValue>: [Javascript object 1]

[Javascript object 1]
title: "test123"

<v-text-field>
value: "test123"
```

As you can see here, the setter is never invoked in the normal operation, and hence your code to save it does not run.

You can solve this by making another computed prop for the title of the offer, and then adding some code to prevent your changes from being made undone.

Let's start with the getter & setter for the title:

```
computed: {
    title: {
        get() {
            return this.offer.title;
        },
        set(title) {
            this.offer = {...this.offer, title};
        }
    },
    // ....
```

Now we need to properly handle this set operation inside our main offer function, because if we don't handle it, and basically modify its returned object, we get into the territory of undefined behaviour, as the value of the computation doesn't match the computation.

```
    // ... 

    offer: {
        get: function () {
            if (this.modifiedOffer) {
                return this.modifiedOffer;
            }
            return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.propOffer))          
        },
        set: function (offer) {
            this.modifiedOffer = offer;
        }
    },
},
data() {
    return: {
        modifiedOffer: undefined,
    };
},
```

After doing this pattern, you now have a stable application, that shows no undefined behaviour, for more functionality, you basicly need to check if the `propOffer` changes, and either forcefully delete the `this.modifiedOffer`, or add more logic to a different computed variable that informs the user there is a data conflict, and ask him to overwrite his data.

Comment: oh I see. This is much more complicated than I thought. I need to check this. Thank you for a great explanation