# vue-draggable - cannot mutate my array directly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sortablejs

I'm using `vue-draggable` to change array elements order. Let's say my array is:

```
data: {
 array1: [{text: 'text1'},{text: 'text2'},{text: 'text3'}]
}
```

on my template I simply use:

```
<draggable v-model="array1" >
v-for etc...
</draggable>
```

And this is working fine.

Now I have to move my code inside component and use `array1` as a prop.

So I move my `array1` to props inside child component:

```
props['array1'],
```

I use my vue-draggable and bam: 
`"[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders."`

I cannot simply declare `array1` inside data, because it's asynchronous. So I write it inside computed:

```
   array2: {
      get: function () {
        //return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.array1))          
        return this.array1.slice()          
      },
      set: function () {
        this.array2
      }
  },
```

and this obviously will not work, because getter is always hardcoded as slice() of prop. I made question yesterday here: [vuejs computed setter of given prop is not reactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119310/vuejs-computed-setter-of-given-prop-is-not-reactive)

So the advice is to write some kind of new computed and add if statement inside `array2` computed:

```
   array2: {
      get: function () {
        if (this.modifiedArray) {
            return this.modifiedArray;
        }
        //return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.array1))          
        return this.array1.slice()          
      },
      set: function () {
        this.proTemplate
      }
  },
```

and I've got a problem with adressing vue-draggable changes to modifiedArray computed, because I cannot change v-model inside draggable:

`<draggable v-model="array2">`

Anyone knows how to change it to get vue-draggable result inside external array/computed?

Comment: you should emit one event to notify the parent component to update the value, once parent component updated props, the child component will be updated also.

Comment: Props are meant to be used in a read-only manner. Nonetheless, as @Sphinx suggested, you can emit an event in order to do the mutation in the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate what i understand of your issue [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Sovalina/p8w4qvv8/)

I used the `clone` method from Lodash library to prevent the `"[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly..."` error.

Hope it helps

Comment: This will not work, because prop[ 'array' ] is asynchronous. This will just clone empty array at the beginning. This is quite tricky :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `list` prop instead of `v-model` according to the [documentation](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#list), as the `list` prop is not immutable as the `v-model` is.

Like so:

```
<draggable :list="array1" >
   v-for etc...
</draggable>
```